# Tourist Visa to Dependent Visa Germany

Tags: visas, germany, family, german-residents

I am in Germany on a long term work permit. I would like to apply for a dependent visa of my wife and kids but not getting the appointment for the dependent visa in the next couple of months. So, Can I get my wife in Germany on a tourist visa and later get her visa changed to the Dependent category? Help is really appreciated.

Comment: You can definitely make a seperate C-Visa application. Refeferece the D-Visa application (with date of interview). Whether they will be combined later is another matter.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get the visa **changed**. You can apply for a different visa while you have a short-stay visa, but a tourist visa has a maximum of 90 days, and might be granted for less.

Answer (score 1):

If they are citizens of a country which is allowed visa free entry in Germany, such as the USA, then they can travel to Germany and apply for residency when they are here.

However, if they are not from such a country then you have to apply for a family reunion visa for your family members in the country where they are currently resident.

If they are already in Germany, then they would have to return home in order to apply for and be granted the visa.

Please bear in mind that the processing of such visas often takes many months.

Please ensure that you and your family meet all the requirements before applying, as this will ensure a smoother quicker application.

You can find more details here:
https://www.germany-visa.org/family-reunion-visa/